# wakanda import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'

Tags: angular, wakanda

I work the tuto wakanda on https://wakanda.github.io/doc/#/tutorial?section=main-routing. When I open app.module.ts, the method import don't working, I have this message:

```
cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser', @angular/core, @angular/forms, @angular/http, @angular/router.
```

I have see in Help/Troubleshooting. Anything is OK.

Comment: Do you have those modules in node_modules folder ?

Comment: I don't have a node_modules in my all project. I use Wakanda entreprise studio v2.0.1. you know how I can create node_module ?

Comment: you just need to Run the web project and wait for the project to be displayed in the browser , this will run an npm install and create a node_modules folder that contains project dependencies (@angular/core, @angular/forms, @angular/http .. ).

Comment: I have this error :  ng serve "--proxyConfig" "proxy.conf.json" "--open" "--port" "4201"

The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js:14:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

Comment: Try to delete node_modules folder and Run again

Comment: My application works again, Thank you